# Stub a standalone module.exports function using rewire

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to `stub` a `module.exports` function. But I have some trouble. I will give you a sudo code of the situation.

*MyController.js*

```
const sendOTPOnPhone = rewire('../../src/services/OtpService/sendOTPOnPhone')

module.exports = async function(req, res) {
         const { error, data } = await sendOTPOnPhone(req.query.phone) //this is I want to stub
         if(error)
           return return res.send(error)
         return res.send(data)
}
```

*sendOTPService.js*

```
module.exports = async function(phone) {
               const result = await fetch(`external-api-call`)
               if(result.status !== 'success')
                  return {
                          error: "Failed to send OTP!",
                          data: null
                  }
               return {
                      error: null,
                      data: result
               }
}
```

*sendOTPTest.js*

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const request = require('supertest')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const rewire = require('rewire')
const sendOTPOnPhone = rewire('../../src/services/OtpService/sendOTPOnPhone')

const app = require('../../src/app')

describe('GET /api/v1/auth/otp/generate', function () {
    it('should generate OTP', async () => {
        let stub = sinon.stub().returns({
            error: null,
            data: "OTP sent"
        })
        sendOTPOnPhone.__set__('sendOTPOnPhone', stub)
        const result = await request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/auth/otp/generate?phone=8576863491')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
        expect(stub.calledOnce).to.be.true
        console.log(result.body)
        // expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved'); 
    })
})
```

Above test is failing, stub is not being called. I don't know what am I missing? If I do this in my sendOTPService:

```
const sendOTP = async function() {}
module.exports = {
  sendOTP
}
```

and this in the controller.

```
const { error, data } = sendOTPOnPhone.sendOTPOnPhone(req.query.phone)
```

It works.
But I  import it like `const {sendOTPOnPhone }  = require('../sendOTPService')` It doesn't work.
I am aware that destructing changes the reference of the object.
Can someone suggest a workaround?
Is it possible to achieve this using `rewire`? OR It can be done with `proxyquire`.
Please can someone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the integration testing solution using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire), you should use [Globally override require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire#globally-override-require).

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const controller = require('./controller');

const app = express();
app.get('/api/v1/auth/otp/generate', controller);

module.exports = app;
```

`controller.js`:

```js
let sendOTPOnPhone = require('./sendOTPOnPhone');

module.exports = async function(req, res) {
  const { error, data } = await sendOTPOnPhone(req.query.phone);
  if (error) return res.send(error);
  return res.send(data);
};
```

`sendOTPOnPhone.js`:

```js
module.exports = async function(phone) {
  const result = await fetch(`external-api-call`);
  if (result.status !== 'success')
    return {
      error: 'Failed to send OTP!',
      data: null,
    };
  return {
    error: null,
    data: result,
  };
};
```

`sendOTP.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('GET /api/v1/auth/otp/generate', function() {
  it('should generate OTP', async () => {
    let stub = sinon.stub().resolves({
      error: null,
      data: { message: 'OTP sent' },
    });
    stub['@global'] = true;
    const app = proxyquire('./app', {
      './sendOTPOnPhone': stub,
    });
    const result = await request(app)
      .get('/api/v1/auth/otp/generate?phone=8576863491')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    console.log(result.body);
  });
});
```

Integration test results with coverage report:

```sh
  GET /api/v1/auth/otp/generate
{ message: 'OTP sent' }
    ✓ should generate OTP (2373ms)


  1 passing (2s)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |   68.75 |       25 |      50 |   73.33 |                   
 app.js            |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.js     |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 5                 
 sendOTPOnPhone.js |      20 |        0 |       0 |      20 | 2-4,8             
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60599945

Comment: Thanks, but getting this error   `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; `. Stub is now being called though.

Comment: Here is my `npm test` command: `"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register --timeout 5000"`, I execute test by running `npm t -- <your file path>`

Comment: `mocha --recursive --exit --timeout 5000` this mine. I added `--timeout 5000` and works now. Why?

Comment: Is default timeout which is two seconds is for all tests or just one?

Comment: It's normal even if we stub every external service and side-effect operations. The test execution time can be affected by the hardware, the number of threads, code performance and so on. The timeout option of `mocha` cli is for each test case. But you can set the timeout for a specific test case. You can find it in the documentation.

Comment: It would be nice of you explaining why we need globally override. What was the problem with my implementation. Does app creates it's own scope when test is being run?

Comment: It's up to you, I just give a demonstration.  For integration tests, because of the code under test reference too many functions/components/services, business logic, web server start/shutdown, resource acquisition/release. so the test execution time will be longer than the unit tests. Set the timeout larger will avoid the timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

I have **answered** a similar **question** here [stub SMS otp method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70447545/14085862) (without using external dependecy like proxyquire)

basically, the problem is with exports. Move your **sendOtp** method to a generalized place e.g User Model or schema.  Import model, stub its function. It should work fine.

you are stubbing imported property called **sendOtp** instead of original function.